# Plotting graph given parametric form satisfying $x=f(t)$ and $y=-f(-t)$

Tags: calculus, contest-math, graphing-functions, parametric

I had to plot the curve given by the parametric definition as follows. In attempting to simplify doing so, here is what I see holds between $x$ and $y$.

> Plot the curve given by $$x=\frac{(t+2)^2}{t+1} ,y=\frac{(t-2)^2}{t-1}$$

---

$$\boxed{x=f(t)\\ y=-f(-t)}$$

Is there somehow we can use that to plot the graph easily. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a new way

Answer (score 1):

write $x$ as $\dfrac{(1+t+1)^2}{t+1} = t+1+2+\dfrac{1}{t+1}$ and $y = t-1 -2 + \dfrac{1}{t-1} $

$$\begin{align} x+y &= 2t \Big(\dfrac{t^2}{t^2-1} \Big) \\
y - x &= 6 - \dfrac{2}{t^2-1}\\
x+y &= t^3 \cdot (6+x-y) \end{align}$$

and now you can just put  value of $t$ in terms of $x,y$

to get $$(8+x-y)^3 = (x+y)^2 (6+x-y) $$
[image]
here is what geogebra gave

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although isn't the final equation too complicated to plot by hand?

Comment: it is not complicated if you rotate the axis and shift the origin

Comment: to be precise you should rotate the axis by $45^o$

Comment: I had done it like that but intimidated by the length of it, I tried to turn to some alternate method that would give an elegant pathway to the graph. Can you think of some way to use the boxed data in the OP?